# Installing python openid library pyoidc but fails due to missing ffi.h

Tags: python, python-2.7, openid, openid-provider

Does anyone know where I should get that file?

Has anyone gotten pyoidc installed and working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the header files for [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi)

What OS are you using?

Redhat and the like:

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

or apt based systems:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

On OSX you might try [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-cffi/gRiL5pSHKnc/8Y-6ZzrXcwAJ)